# Creating new package for magento

Tags: magento, module

When I try to install new extension created by me gives me error, 
CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x
Invalid stability
Invalid channel URL
Empty authors section
Empty package contents section
I am creating package, going to Magento connect, package extension. I think I am following all things that are needed to create package. Same module is working on site, but when I create package and delete module then it's not working. I have also tested  stability, dependencies, etc. Still not working. How can I get more information about errors I am getting?

Answer (score 0):

It was also hard for me to figure it out

it's about a filename: ExtraWatch-1.0.0.tgz

is a correct format.

It has to contain package.xml

something similar like this one (you'll find other examples of package.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <package>
        <name>ExtraWatch</name>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <stability>devel</stability>
        <license>GPL</license>
        <channel>community</channel>
        <extends/>
        <summary>asdf</summary>
        <description>description</description>
        <notes>test</notes>
        <authors>
            <author>
                <name>Matto</name>
                <user>matto3c</user>  
                <email>foo@codegravity.com</email>
            </author>
        </authors>
        <date>2012-08-17</date>
        <time>08:22:34</time>
        <contents>
            <target name="magelocal">
                <dir name="CodeGravity">
                    <dir name="ExtraWatch">
                        <dir name="Block">
                            <dir name="Adminhtml">
                                <dir name="ExtraWatch">
                                    <file name="Edit.php"/>
                                </dir>
                            </dir>
                        </dir>
                    </dir>
                </dir>
            </target>
        </contents>

        <compatible/>
        <dependencies><required><php><min>1.0.0</min><max>5.5.0</max></php></required></dependencies>
    </package>
```